# When report don't ask for two fields it starts to divide by zero

Tags: sql

I have trouble with these two statements.

Because when the report doesn't ask columns "Invboxamount" or/and freebox, then it whole query returns error that it's deciding to "divide with zero error"

What should I do too not affect whole query by when these two columns are asked?

Maybe there is better solution to write this

```
sum (Case when bm.CaseQTY IS NULL then (k.postedqty / mm.CaseQTY) else (k.postedqty / bm.CaseQTY) End) 
    as Invboxamount,
sum (Case when bm.CaseQTY IS NULL then ((k.postedqty-k.reservordered-k.reservphysical-k.picked+k.registered) / mm.CaseQTY) else ((k.postedqty-k.reservordered-k.reservphysical-k.picked+k.registered) /bm.CaseQTY) End)
    as Freebox
```

Comment: Some sample data would be really helpful here.

Comment: Apparently, either one (or both) of the `CaseQTY` fields is zero (which, by the way, is not the same as `NULL`). When that is the case, what result do you _expect_ from your query? An obvious choice would be to return `NULL`, but it's up to your requirements. Please specify in full detail.

Answer (score 0):

replace `CaseQTY` with `coalesce(CaseQTY,1)` within every denominator occurence such as

```
sum (Case when bm.CaseQTY IS NULL then 
               (k.postedqty / coalesce(mm.CaseQTY,1)) 
          else (k.postedqty / coalesce(bm.CaseQTY,1)) 
           end) as Invboxamount,
sum (Case when bm.CaseQTY IS NULL then 
              ((k.postedqty-k.reservordered-k.reservphysical-k.picked+k.registered) 
               / coalesce(mm.CaseQTY,1) ) 
          else 
              ((k.postedqty-k.reservordered-k.reservphysical-k.picked+k.registered) 
               / coalesce(bm.CaseQTY,1) ) 
          end) as Freebox
```

Comment: Mapping `x / 0` to `x` is often OK-ish in inventory software; if denominator is zero, typically so is numerator. But you are treading on thin ice here. I sure wouldn't generalize this to every possible application. My preference would be to yield `NULL` when division by zero is imminent.